# Magnific-Popup Loading iframe from non-video players URL

Tags: magnific-popup

I was just wondering how I go about firing a magnific-popup with an iframe NOT from a video site.

I'm trying to load a page from another site that my company owns and I can't seem to get it to do anything other than open the url in a new page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let me know if code examples will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add such option to init code of popup, and iframe src will match href.

```
iframe: {
    patterns: {
        yourcustomsource: {
            index: '',
            src: '%id%'
        }
    }
}
```

Also, take a look at - http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/details/jnohA

Comment: It still just opens in a new page. Below is the code I'm using:     <a class="shimmerButton planLink" href="mywebsite.com/signup_work/new">Some Text</a>  
  
$(document).ready(function() {  
 $('.planLink').magnificPopup({  
 type: 'iframe'  
 iframe: { patterns: {  
 mywebsitename: { index: '', src: '%id%' } 
 } }, }); });

Comment: Nevermind. Found that I was just missing a comma. Thanks for the help.